# SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS missing deadlock section

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-deadlocks

We are experiencing a deadlock and trying to get information about it from the InnoDB engine, but we get no LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK section. Could anyone help me understand why this might be? Is there some configuration that could be missing?

Thanks!

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

=====================================
130325 15:37:30 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
....
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
....
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
....
--------
FILE I/O
--------
....
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
....
---
LOG
---
....
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
....
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
....
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? We received a Rails exception saying there is a deadlock, however we got the same when looking at the innodb status.

Comment: It seems to be stored for a few seconds only: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/28951

Answer (score 0):

Your server has not had any deadlocks since startup, so the section is omitted. Why do you think you have deadlocked?

Comment: I had deadlocks too, but nothing in INNODB STATUS. It seems to disappear after a while.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the new 5.6 variable: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_print_all_deadlocks, so that you can log all deadlocks.

Or deal with the error in your application (1213), see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-error-codes.html.